# how to pass data from one app to another in matlab gui (using app designer)

Tags: matlab

I am designing a Gui whereby I will type something on the first app and I want it to appear on the second app. these two apps are linked to each other i.e app 1 is the first page of GUI and app 2 is the second page.

Comment: Do you have two separate windows, or tabs (like [uitabgroup](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitabgroup.html)). Please add more details to your question, and ideally a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show how the two GUIs are linked.

Comment: Two separate windows

Answer (score 1):

It's simple when App1 holds a handle to App2.

App1:

```
properties (Access = private)
    hApp2 % Handle to app2
end
```

Executing App2 from App1:

```
% Code that executes after component creation
function startupFcn(app)
    app.hApp2 = App2;
end
```

Setting a label in App2 from App1 when button is pressed:

```
% Button button pushed function
function ButtonButtonPushed(app)
    app.hApp2.Label.Text = 'Button Pressed';
end
```

---

App1 complete code (sample):

```
classdef App1 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure matlab.ui.Figure         % UI Figure
        Button   matlab.ui.control.Button % Button
    end


    properties (Access = private)
        hApp2 % Handle to app2
    end


    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)
            app.hApp2 = App2;
        end

        % Button button pushed function
        function ButtonButtonPushed(app)
            app.hApp2.Label.Text = 'Button Pressed';
        end
    end

    % App initialization and construction
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure
            app.UIFigure = uifigure;
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 640 480];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';
            setAutoResize(app, app.UIFigure, true)

            % Create Button
            app.Button = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.Button.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @ButtonButtonPushed);
            app.Button.Position = [231 261 153 61];
        end
    end

    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = App1()

            % Create and configure components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

---

App2 complete code (sample):

```
classdef App2 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure matlab.ui.Figure        % UI Figure
        Label    matlab.ui.control.Label % Label
    end

    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)

        end
    end

    % App initialization and construction
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure
            app.UIFigure = uifigure;
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 640 480];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';
            setAutoResize(app, app.UIFigure, true)

            % Create Label
            app.Label = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.Label.Position = [236 338 63 21];
        end
    end

    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = App2()

            % Create and configure components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```